# How can I find out the cluster size of an exfat partition?

Tags: exfat

How can I find out the cluster size of an exfat partition?
It appears that fsutil only has a command for ntsf partition
.

Comment: can't you do this with `fsinfo sectorinfo` ?

Comment: That tells me there are 512 bytes per sector; I'm not sure that sectors and clusters are the same thing

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it on my Ubuntu with exfat-utils package installed.

```
$ sudo dumpexfat /dev/sdb1
Volume label                        
Volume serial number      0xb631210e
FS version                       1.0
Sector size                      512
Cluster size                   32768
Sectors count             1953523120
Free sectors              1953276800
Clusters count              30520069
Free clusters               30519950
First sector                       0
FAT first sector                 128
FAT sectors count             238528
First cluster sector          238656
Root directory cluster           120
Volume state                  0x0002
FATs count                         1
Drive number                    0x80
Allocated space                   0%
```